# How to find plurals with Google Cloud Natural Language API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-nl

The Google Cloud Natural Language API can be used to analyse text and return a syntactic parse tree with each word labeled with parts-of-speech tags.

Is there a way to deturmine if a noun is plural or not?

If Google Cloud NL is able to work out the lemma then perhaps the information is there but not returned through the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

With the NL API's GA launch, the `annotateText` endpoint now returns a `number` key for each token indicating whether word is singular, plural, or dual. For the sentence "There are some cats here," the API returns the following token data for 'cats' (notice that `number` is `PLURAL`):

```
{
      "text": {
        "content": "cats",
        "beginOffset": -1
      },
      "partOfSpeech": {
        "tag": "NOUN",
        "aspect": "ASPECT_UNKNOWN",
        "case": "CASE_UNKNOWN",
        "form": "FORM_UNKNOWN",
        "gender": "GENDER_UNKNOWN",
        "mood": "MOOD_UNKNOWN",
        "number": "PLURAL",
        "person": "PERSON_UNKNOWN",
        "proper": "PROPER_UNKNOWN",
        "reciprocity": "RECIPROCITY_UNKNOWN",
        "tense": "TENSE_UNKNOWN",
        "voice": "VOICE_UNKNOWN"
      },
      "dependencyEdge": {
        "headTokenIndex": 1,
        "label": "DOBJ"
      },
      "lemma": "cat"
}
```

See the full documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/reference/rest/v1/Token).

Comment: I can see that this feature has now been added but I am not sure if it is working correctly? It seems to be awful at detecting plurals!

I have tried putting simple sentences into the API demo on https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/

Most of the time it gives the incorrect result.

We ate bananas for breakfast. Bananas = SINGULAR?
She picked cherries for a living. Cherries = SINGULAR?
The electrons orbit the nucleus. Electrons = SINGULAR?

Surely these should be plural?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for trying out the NL API.

Right now there isn't a clean way to detect plurals other than to note that the base word is different than the lemma and guess whether it's plural (in English, perhaps it ends in an -s).

However, we plan to release a much better way of detecting morphological information like plurality, so stay tuned.

Comment: See Sara's comment that explains how to do this now that morphology is live.